# No right arrow displayed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="content">  
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-dividertheme="b">
        <li data-role="list-divider" >Transition Effects</li>
        <li><a href="#second">Slide</a></li>
        <li><a href="TestPage1.htm"![enter image description here][1] data-transition="slideup">Slide Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="TestPage1.htm" data-transition="slidedown">Slide Down</a></li>
        <li data-role="list-divider">Other Effects</li>
        <li><a href="TestPage.html" data-transition="pop">Pop</a></li>
        <li><a href="TestPage.html" data-transition="flip">Flip</a></li>
        <li><a href="TestPage.html" data-transition="fade">Fade</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

No right arrow get displayed. I am using JQuery Mobile 1.0a4.1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.js"></script>
```

What can be the cause? I copied jquery css and js in my local folder

[image]

Comment: I'm sure something is the cause. But you'll need to explain a bit more to find it.

Comment: Nothing special used. I am a newbie to JQuery

Comment: Is it linking to an image or a character? Does the image exist? Is the path being resolved correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to download the images as well and put them in the `images` folder

They can be found in the zip file at http://jquerymobile.com/download/

the link is where it says

- *Zip File: jquery-mobile-1.0a4.1.zip*
  (JavaScript, CSS, **and images**)

Answer (score 1):

you must be missing the images folder. The css refers to images folder for icons. (icons-36-white.png in your case.)

Comment: how to download images folder?

Comment: download the zip file from here http://jquerymobile.com/download/ . The zip has the js, css and images folder.